# How can I get the object id of a tkinter canvas item built by a self-defined class?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, objectid

I have defined the class state, which consists out of two tkinter canvas items. After adding an instance of this class to a tkinter canvas, I want to identify the instance by the left mouse button. I have used the canvas find_overlapping-method for this. But of course I only get the canvas item id of the instance instead of the object id (which I need for calling methods on the instances of the class state). How can I derive the object id from the canvas item id? Please look into this example:

```
from tkinter import *  

class state():
    def __init__(self, canvas, x_position, y_position, *args, **kwargs):
        self.oval = canvas.create_oval(x_position-20, y_position-20, x_position+20, y_position+20, fill='cyan')
        self.text = canvas.create_text(x_position, y_position, text='S1')

x, y= 40, 40
def insert_state(canvas):
    global x, y
    global id
    id = state(canvas, x, y)
    x += 40
    y += 40

def identify(event, canvas):
    canvas_item_id = canvas.find_overlapping(event.x,event.y,event.x,event.y)
    print("Found canvas item with id ", canvas_item_id)

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.grid()
button1 = Button(root, text='add state')
button1.grid()
button1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, canvas=canvas : insert_state (canvas))
canvas.bind ('<Button-1>', lambda event, canvas=canvas : identify     (event, canvas))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by *object ID*? For a canvas item, there is only item ID.  You can use `canvas.itemconfigure(item_id, ...)` to change the options of the canvas item.

Comment: @acw1668: I mean the id I get with the code line "id = state(canvas, x, y)". It is kind of lost, as it gets a new value at any time a new state is inserted. I need this id to call a method for an instance of the class state.

Comment: The return of `state(...)` is an instance (reference) of the class `state`, you can use this instance to call any function inside class `state`.

Comment: @acw1668: Yes you are right. But the user will first insert several states. Then afterwards the user will select 1 of the states by the left mouse button in order to change an attribute of this state (by calling a method for this instance). So the instance (reference) is not available at this moment.

Comment: You can use a list to store those instances of `state` and use a method inside `state` to check which instance of `state` contains the returned canvas item IDs.

Comment: @acw1668: I will try to create such a list. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: You say you want to call methods on the object represented by the canvas item, but your object has no methods. Do you really need to call methods on the object, or do you just need to be able to access the oval or text items, such as being able to move both of them at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment of acw1668, I have solved the problem:
I added a dictionary as a class variable.
At any time when a new instance of the class is created,
the dictionary gets a new entry.
Each entry has as key the Canvas Item ID.
The value of each entry is the reference of the instance.
So by looking into this dictionary I am able to convert Canvas Item IDs into references and afterwards I can call methods for each reference (my example has no such methods in order to keep it simple).
Sorry for perhaps being not so exact in my explanation,
I am new to SW development.

Updated code:

```
from tkinter import *  

class state():
    state_dict = {} # NEW DICTIONARY
    def __init__(self, canvas, x_position, y_position, *args, **kwargs):
        self.oval = canvas.create_oval(x_position-20, y_position-20, x_position+20, y_position+20, fill='cyan')
        self.text = canvas.create_text(x_position, y_position, text='S1')
        state.state_dict[self.oval] = self # NEW ENTRY TO THE DICTIONARY

x, y= 40, 40
def insert_state(canvas):
    global x, y
    global id
    id = state(canvas, x, y)
    x += 40
    y += 40

def identify(event, canvas):
    canvas_item_id = canvas.find_overlapping(event.x,event.y,event.x,event.y)
    print("Found canvas item with id ", canvas_item_id[0])
    print("Found reference ", state.state_dict[canvas_item_id[0]]) # SOLVED

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.grid()
button1 = Button(root, text='add state')
button1.grid()
button1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, canvas=canvas : insert_state (canvas))
canvas.bind ('<Button-1>', lambda event, canvas=canvas : identify     (event, canvas))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I hope that this code has solved your problem(only then you should post it as an answer. If not then you can edit your question to include the new code. ) Your answer can be improved by adding a line or two to explain what went wrong in your code and how you fixed it. This will help future readers to understand the answer more clearly.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Matthias says "I have fixed the code". That sounds like an answer to me. As AbhyudayVaish notes, though, it would be much improved with an explanation.